# What is Dokkan Awakening and who can do it?

Tags: dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle

I know that you can Z-Awaken all characters, but what exactly does Dokkan Awakening do?

From what I gather, not all characters are eligible for this type of awakening. Is there any way to tell what characters are eligible? Are the tokens only available from certain events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dokkan Awakening is just another progression after Z-Awakening. It lets you increase the rarity of cards that can be Dokkan awakened. Here is the list of characters:

- Frieza (All forms) to *Golden Frieza (STR, TEQ, AGL, INT)*
- SR Android 13 (TEQ) to SSR Super Android 13 (TEQ)*
- R Gohan (Teen)(PHY) to SR Super Saiyan Gohan (Teen)(PHY)
- SR Bojack (STR) to SSR Full Power Bojack (STR)
- SR Master Roshi (AGL) to SSR Master Roshi (Max Power)(AGL)
- SR Master Roshi (TEQ) to SSR Master Roshi (Max Power)(TEQ)
- R Chi-Chi (STR) to SR Chi-Chi (Kid)(STR)
- R Chi-Chi (INT) to SR Chi-Chi (Kid)(INT)
- SR Cooler (INT) to SSR Cooler (Final Form)(INT)
- R Gohan (Adolescent)(STR) to SR Great Saiyaman Nr.1 (STR)
- SR Gohan (Adolesent)(AGL) to SSR Great Saiyaman Nr.1 (AGL)
- SR Videl (TEQ) to SSR Great Saiyaman Nr.2 (TEQ)
- SR Videl (STR) to SSR Great Saiyaman Nr.2 (STR)
- R Krillin (STR) to SR Krillin (Kid)(STR)
- R Goku (INT) to SR Super Saiyan Goku (INT)
- SR Super Saiyan Goku (PHY) to SSR Super Saiyan God Goku (PHY)
- R Goku (TEQ) to SR Super Saiyan Goku (TEQ)
- SR Broly (PHY) to SSR Super Saiyan Broly (PHY)
- SSR Legendary Super Saiyan Broly (STR) to UR Legendary Super Saiyan Broly (STR)